# migrating from Apache Archiva to Nexus 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3, archiva

I am trying to move all repositories I am using to Nexus 3. I use Apache Archiva as a Maven repository. I read that it's possible to copy repos between Archiva and Nexus 2. Is there any way to do the same with Nexus 3 ?

Comment: Have a look here, you can use these scripts to import the content:  https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-import-scripts

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. I meant Archiva to Nexus3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do a workaround and succeeded. I created an instance of Nexus2 and migrated Archiva there. After that I have used the upgrade agent from Capabilities to migrate from Nexus2 to 3. Not a complicated way and is fast as well.